# deriving laplace of (t^n)

Tags: solution-verification, laplace-transform

im trying to derive laplace of $\mathcal{L}\left\{ t^n \right\}$

sorry my mathjax skills are bad i tried my best to write it clear.
i can solve the equation by following with khan academy video however i wanted to solve it
with my own way and i find trouble in doing that didnt practice math in long time so im restudying calculus again:

$$
\mathcal{L}\left\{ t^n \right\}  
= \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-st}\;\mathrm{d}t
$$

$$ let \text{ } {u} = e^{-st}$$
$$ du = -s e^{-st} dt$$
$$ let \text{ } {dv} = t^{n}dt$$
$$ v = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

intgration by parts
$$ \int{uv'} = uv - \int{vu'}$$

$$ [e^{-st} * \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}] \Big|_0^\infty - \int\limits_0^\infty {\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}*(-s*e^{-st})dt}$$

$$ 0 + \frac{s}{n+1} \int_0^\infty{t^{n+1} * e^{-st}\text{ }\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$ \frac{s}{n+1} \mathcal{L}{(t^{n+1})}$$
$$ \frac{s}{n+1} * \frac{s}{n+2} * \mathcal{L}{(t^{n+2})}$$
$$ \frac{s}{n+1} * \frac{s}{n+2} * \frac{s}{n+3} * \mathcal{L}{(t^{n+3})}$$

where is my mistake ?

Comment: Integrate $e^{-st}$ and differentiate $t^n$, not the other way round. Then you can get $\mathcal{L}\left\{ t^n \right\}$ in terms of $\mathcal{L}\left\{ t^{n-1} \right\}$.

Comment: hey paul i solved it with letting u = $t^{2}$ however i wanted to solve it with this way.
i mean shouldnt both ways should give same answer?

Comment: There is a more shorter way if you know Gamma function

Comment: You will just keep increasing n that way though, so it is not helpful. You will end up with an infinite (converging) sum with an integral remainder each iteration which is converging to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, actually you are very close to a solution. let's notice that
$$
\mathcal{L}\{1\}(s)=\intop_0^{\infty}e^{-st}dt=-\frac{1}{s}\left[e^{-st}\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}=\frac{1}{s}
$$
you have proven already that $\mathcal{L}\{t^n\}=\frac{s}{n+1}\cdot\mathcal{L}\{t^{n+1}\}$, so we can guess that the general  formula will be $\mathcal{L}\{t^n\}=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$ and prove it by induction.

**the base case $n=0$:** we've already proven

**induction step $n\Rightarrow n+1$:** let us assume that $\mathcal{L}\{t^n\}=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$ and prove that $\mathcal{L}\{t^{n+1}\}=\frac{(n+1)!}{s^{n+2}}$.

as you proved, we know that $\mathcal{L}\{t^n\}=\frac{s}{n+1}\cdot\mathcal{L}\{t^{n+1}\}$, so by our induction hypothesis we can conclude that $\frac{s}{n+1}\cdot\mathcal{L}\{t^{n+1}\}=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$ and after dividing by $\frac{s}{n+1}$ we will get $\mathcal{L}\{t^{n+1}\}=\frac{n+1}{s}\cdot\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}=\frac{(n+1)!}{s^{n+2}}$ as desired.